# Can't install PDO_SQLITE? Later version

Tags: php, sqlite, ubuntu, pdo

I am trying to get the PDO_SQLITE extension because I have to read a SQLite database. I know I miss this module because I get the error message "could not find driver".

But when I try to install it through "sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite" it says I have a later version of it and cannot install it.

Anyone know how I can go around this problem? Even tried with aptitude and it just had one option which was to not install it.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to some sort of problem with dependencies or a weird third party repository.

While I've never had an issue with this myself, doing a little bit of research shows that this *might* work.

```
$ apt-get --purge remove php*
$ sudo apt-get install php5 php5-sqlite php5-mysql
$ sudo apt-get install php-pear php-apc php5-curl
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

You'll of course want to backup any special configurations that you've put in place and keep note of all the php 'plugins' you need to have installed before doing this.

You can also try instead of purging all of everything that has to do with php, just doing `sqlite`

$ sudo apt-get --purge remove sqlite3
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove php5-sqlite

and trying to install them at this point.

I would also like to state that personally, I try to use `apt-get` as little as possible.  I tend to use `aptitude` as it seems to have better dependency management.  If you want to give that a go you can install it by:  `sudo apt-get install aptitude`.  It accepts most apt-get commands, and if you just type `aptitude` into your console it has a nifty console interface.